# TypeError: response.redirect is not a function

Tags: javascript, express

I need help...

So, I have this code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
//Sites
// Landingpage CourseWorkers ----------------------------------------
app_courseworkers = require('./sites/app')
app_https_courseworkers = (req, response) => response.redirect("https://courseworkers.com")
```

But when I run it on the server I get the message:

```
0|index  | TypeError: response.redirect is not a function
0|index  |     at Object.app_https_courseworkers [as handler] (/var/www/html/courseworkers/index.js:9:55)
0|index  |     at Server.overallHandler (/var/www/html/courseworkers/node_modules/vhttps/lib/init.js:103:25)
0|index  |     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
0|index  |     at Server.emit (events.js:214:7)
0|index  |     at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:619:12)
0|index  |     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:115:23)
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Note: Running in localhost it goes normally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to redirect to an external URL when someone goes to a specific URL on your site, try this:

```
app.get("/course", (req, res) => {
  res.redirect("https://courseworkers.com");
});
```

My guess is, you are trying to call `app_https_courseworkers(req, response)`, but you aren't actually passing in a valid response object.

Comment: nope, actually my aplication runs in a vhost which can handle many domains and redirects each one to its correct path and application

Comment: so making a route for each would be troublesome  (it worked before when I made some visual changes it stopped working)

Comment: but you actually gave me a nice idea, let me try something, brb

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could at least spark an idea. Let me know what you find.

Comment: opdate: I made it work, aparently I was passing the wrong application in the server usage for the vhost, that made a loop in which the header was already parsed so It couldn't redirect anymore

Comment: Thanks anyway Jonathan :) you helped a lot